# MongoDB Stich Sync with update query does not work in Android

Tags: android, mongodb

```
    Document filter = new Document();
    filter.put("text", "hii");
    Document update = new Document();
    update.put("text", "prakash");
    update.put("owner_id", _client.getAuth().getUser().getId());
    update.put("checked", false);

    Task<SyncUpdateResult> res=getItemsCollection().sync().updateMany(filter, update);
    res.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<SyncUpdateResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@android.support.annotation.NonNull Task<SyncUpdateResult> task) {

        }

    });
```

Above code is for Update MongoDB atlas record with Sync option from android device(means if internet is available then app will sync data to mongodb cloud) 
I used Delete with Sync , Insert with Sync its works fine but if i try Update with Sync then it does not work
If anyone know whats issue with Sync Update

Error occures like Invalid BSON field name nae

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I solved above issue by query using objectId below is code.

```
    String datas=data_val.getText().toString();

    final Document query = new Document();
    query.put("_id", objectId);


    final Document set = new Document();
    set.append("text", datas);
    set.put("owner_id", _client.getAuth().getUser().getId());
    set.put("checked", true);


    Log.d("Data4455",""+objectId);
    final Document update = new Document();
    update.put("$set", set);

    remoteCollection.sync().updateOne(query,update,new SyncUpdateOptions().upsert(true)).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@android.support.annotation.NonNull Task task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                findData();
            }
            else
                Log.d("Data4455","error"+" "+task.getException().getMessage());
        }
    });
```

First Document is to query particular record that you want to update in mongoDB using "_id" and i got "objectId" which was retrived from mongoDB.

Second Document defines what are the values that you wanna update in mongoDB.

Third Document set update Document.

finally call  remoteCollection.sync().updateOne(query,update) to update data.
It will definetly work Thank you.